# convert YAML file list in to objects using Java

Tags: java, yaml

Trying to convert following YAML to JAVA class object for Data and Emp.

The YAML data:

```
# -- start data --
data:
  - version: 1
  - query: 'select id, name, ip;'
  - [ id, name, ip ]
  - [ 0, unknown, 0 ]
  - [ 6481089589324858364, admin, 10.128.1.114 ]
  - [ 6481312372191345669, user1, 2.2.250.1]
# -- end data -- 
# -- start emp --
emp:
  - version: 1
  - query: 'select id, name, number;'
  - [ id, empname, number ]
  - [ 648, emp1, 1 ]
  - [ 645, emp2, 2 ]
# -- end emp --
```

The Java code:

```
Entry entry = Yaml.loadType(file, Entry.class); //--> parses it as list

public class Entry {
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonProperty
    List<Data> data;

    public List<Data> getdata() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Data> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
//similarly List<Employee> emp;
}
```

Where Employee and Data classes are POJO's.  Any link/help on how to convert YAML file list into Java objects would be appreciated.

Few more things:

- some lines are invalid in list like ( - version: 1) etc
- Id's are really big number so it gets parsed as double
- Datamapper kept throwing missing method errors
- Or Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token for '['

Comment: I think you need to look at YAML specs for nested lists. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333975/nested-lists-in-yaml (so you can deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList)

Comment: You need to show your code for `Data` and `Employee`. Also, include the exact error message; from what you write, it is not clear what error you get. Since you are using a List, I can already tell you that you need to add a [TypeDefinition](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-type-safe-collections) so that SnakeYaml knows the type of the list's items.

Comment: Data and Employee are POJO's.  I used JYAML..