# How to nest objects and arrays in a YAML file?

Tags: javascript, yaml, markdown

I currently have this JS array that I want to turn into a YAML file. I tried looking things up and I know how to make an object and array, but not how to nest them.

```
cartParams: [
    {
        title: Leg type,
        options: [
            Round, 
            Square
        ]
    },
    {
        title: Leg width / diameter,
        options: [
            1.00 inches,
            1.25 inches,
            1.50 inches,
            1.75 inches,
            2.00 inches
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Just a tip, some text editors will allow you to preview your YAML.  What text editors are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your YAML file could look like this:

```
cartParams:
  - title: Leg type 
    options:
      - Round
      - Square
  - title: Leg width / diameter 
    options:
      - 1.00 inches
      - 1.25 inches
      - 1.50 inches
      - 1.75 inches
      - 2.00 inches
```

By the way, YAML is a superset of JSON, which means that every JSON object is also a valid YAML object. Therefore, you could use the JSON representation of the object as well.

For more information about nesting lists using YAML-specific syntax, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16335038/942648

Answer (score 1):

```
cartParams:
  - title: Leg type 
    options: [
     Round,
     Square
    ]
  - title: Leg width / diameter 
    options: [
     1.00 inches,
     1.25 inches,
     1.50 inches,
     1.75 inches,
     2.00 inches
    ]
```

Should output the following:

```
{
  "cartParams": [
    {
      "options": [
        "Round", 
        "Square"
      ], 
      "title": "Leg type"
    }, 
    {
      "options": [
        "1.00 inches", 
        "1.25 inches", 
        "1.50 inches", 
        "1.75 inches", 
        "2.00 inches"
      ], 
      "title": "Leg width / diameter"
    }
  ]
}
```